# Does anybody know how to terminate an ESP8266 http web server / access point

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am building a device with arduino where I connect to my Esp8266 board (which is temporarily serving as an acces point) through my phone's browser. Once I enter my ssid and paswword it connects to my router fine. However when using an api it gets confused as it is still serving as an access point. I am using the relevant libraries

The wireless access point goes down forever and the device just becomes connected to the router and does API stuff so there is no weird interference and causing the board to crash

Comment: libraries were #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h> #include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do it. You use these two

void close();
void stop();